# Skip alphabets O, I, Z in CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to generate 6 digit random numbers (100,000 random numbers) in the format `22AA22 (Number+Number+Alphabet+Alphabet+Number+Number)` in excel.

```
Number = 2 to 9 Excluding 0 and 1
Alphabet (in CAPS) = A to Y Excluding O, I, Z
```

I am using

```
=RANDBETWEEN(2,9)&RANDBETWEEN(2,9)&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&RANDBETWEEN(2,9)&RANDBETWEEN(2,9)
```

In `CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))` how can I skip alphabets O, I, Z (both lower and capital).

Comment: Why do you need to skip '*both lower and capital*' if you are only generating capitals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the RANDBETWEEN into three and use CHOOSE with another RANDBETWEEN:

```
CHAR(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),RANDBETWEEN(65,72),RANDBETWEEN(74,78),RANDBETWEEN(80,89)))
```

so:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(2,9)&RANDBETWEEN(2,9)&CHAR(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),RANDBETWEEN(65,72),RANDBETWEEN(74,78),RANDBETWEEN(80,89)))&CHAR(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),RANDBETWEEN(65,72),RANDBETWEEN(74,78),RANDBETWEEN(80,89)))&RANDBETWEEN(2,9)&RANDBETWEEN(2,9)
```

Comment: CHAR(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),RANDBETWEEN(65,72),RANDBETWEEN(74,78),RANDBETWEEN(80,89)))&CHAR(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),RANDBETWEEN(65,72),RANDBETWEEN(74,78),RANDBETWEEN(80,89))). I need to understand this now @scott. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively - to Scott Craner's solution - you can also just list the available options and then get a random number from the list:

```
=CHAR(INDEX({65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,74,75,76,77,78,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89},RANDBETWEEN(1,23)))
```

Comment: I actually prefer this to @Scott's because you get a more even distribution of letters. Could shorten it to =MID("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXY",RANDBETWEEN(1,23),1)